# insertRow() not working with FOR loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a JavaScript code to add multiple rows according to the number submited in an input text box. I am trying to do that by using a FOR loop but for some reason it does not work. Can you explain to me why it does not insert as many rows as the value from input text box??? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
    <br><meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Insert rows in a Table</title>  
</head>
<body>  
    <table id="table" border="1">  
        <tr>
            <td>Row1 cell1</td>  
            <td>Row1 cell2</td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>Row2 cell1</td>  
            <td>Row2 cell2</td>
        </tr>  
    </table><br>  
    <form>
        Type in a number:<input id="input" type="text" value=""}>
        <input type="button" onclick="insert_Row()" value="add row(s)">
    </form><br/>
    <p id="p"></p>

    <script>

        var tableId = document.getElementById("table");

        function insert_Row(){
            var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
            var number = Number(input);

            for(i=0;i<number;i++){
                var ii = i+1;
                var newTR = table.insertRow(i);
                var newTD1 = newTR.insertCell(i);
                var newTD2 = newTR.insertCell(ii);
                newTD1.innerHTML = "Row " + i + " Cell "+ i;
                newTD2.innerHTML = "Row " + i + " Cell "+ ii;
            };
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you defining `table` and `newTR`?

Comment: `var tableId = document.getElementById("table");` should be `var table = document.getElementById("table");`

Comment: Exactly right. He confused `tableid` with `table`. That's how I answered this

Comment: The problem is you need to have cells starting from 0,1,2..etc

Comment: See my working answer below

Comment: @ann.onimus07: See if my answer below is what you want. You can also take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/ujvkqs0f/

Comment: OK. **Thanks Dom**, **Mike Christensen** and **Richard Hamilton** for helping me with **tableId** and **table** but the FOR loop still does not work.

Comment: Check out Sandeep's code snippet or my jsfiddle. Looks like the for loop works for both

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `document.getElementById` declarations.

Also, it sounds like you want to insert the rows at the end of your table. In which case, your code will look like this.

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var numRows = document.querySelectorAll("tr").length;

function insert_Row(){
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var number = Number(input);

    for (var i = numRows; i < number; i++) {
        var ii = 0;
        var ij = 1;
        var newTR = table.insertRow(i);
        var newTD1 = newTR.insertCell(ii);
        var newTD2 = newTR.insertCell(ij);
        newTD1.innerHTML = "Row " + (i + 1) + " Cell "+ (ii +1);
        newTD2.innerHTML = "Row " + (i + 1) + " Cell "+ (ij + 1);
    };
};
```

To use `document.getElementById`, you need to add an id attribute to your input tag like so.

```
<input id="myInput" type="button" onclick="insert_Row()" value="add row(s)">
```

Here is the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vgwk00zm/2/

Comment: `insertCell()` is a JavaScript method. See here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is irrespective of the row number, cells should start from 0,1,2 and so on which is not happening in your code. For the 0th iteration your code works fine, but later on, the cells do not start from 0. Hence the problem

Fix: Since you plan to  have only 2 cells for each row, do it like this:

```js
var tableId = document.getElementById("table");

  function insert_Row() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var number = Number(input);
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      var j = 0; // First Cell
      var k = 1; // Second Cell
      var newTR = table.insertRow(i);
      var newTD1 = newTR.insertCell(j);

      newTD1.innerHTML = "Row " + i + " Cell " + j;
      var newTD2 = newTR.insertCell(k);
      newTD2.innerHTML = "Row " + i + " Cell " + k;
    };
  };
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">

</table>
<br>
<form>
  Type in a number:
  <input id="input" type="text" value=""/>
  <input type="button" onclick="insert_Row()" value="add row(s)">
</form>
<br/>
<p id="p"></p>
```

Comment: @RichardHamilton: Yes.. I meant to add a `/>`. Corrected

Comment: Thank you very much, **Sandeep Nayak** , for your prompt answer and solution to my problem.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this answer. One, it doesn't show the table rows that already exists. Two, the HTML starts the count at 0, when I think it should start at 1. You should use something like ` newTD1.innerHTML = "Row " + (i + 1) + " Cell " + (j + 1);`

Comment: Thanks, **Richard Hamilton** , I did not know it is possible to do `(i+1)`. I am a beginner.